# Need to replace +/- characters with html codes (for example) &#8212; in small piece of jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a fairly mundane piece jQuery that toggles a div's visibility when a + is clicked and hides it when a - is clicked (the + changes to a - when clicked).  The problem is that  the +/- toggler follows some text that sometimes has a + or - in it and both toggle.  For instance:  Find out more about blah-blah +.  When clicked, the plus changes to a minus. When clicked again, both minuses change to pluses.

I thought if i just changed the + to a `&#43;` and a minus to a `&#8212`; in the jquery it would solve the problem, but it doesn't work.  The div visibility toggles on/off but the plus/minus symbols don't change.

Here is the script:

```
function toggleSpecial(element)
{
    jQuery(element).next(".hidden").slideToggle("fast"); 
    jQuery(element).html(function(i,html) {
        if (html.indexOf('+') != -1 ){
           html = html.replace('+','-');
        } else {
           html = html.replace('-','+');
        }
        return html;
    });
}
```

Here is the script with HTML codes replacing the + and - which doesn't work.

```
function toggleSpecial(element)
{
    jQuery(element).next(".hidden").slideToggle("fast"); 
    jQuery(element).html(function(i,html) {
        if (html.indexOf('&#43;') != -1 ){
           html = html.replace('&#43;','&#8212;');
        } else {
           html = html.replace('&#8212;','&#43;');
        }
        return html;
    });
}
```

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong or suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: why dont you enclose the + in a div and only toggle within that div?

Comment: He/she is likely clicking on an `a`, and we all know that `a`s are inline elements while `div`s are block elements.  `<span>` is what he/she wants, assuming he/she wants to pass validation!

Comment: If the answer I gave below was the one you were looking for, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basing your visibility toggling off of something totally arbitrary.  Why not just see if it's visible or not?  Additionally, you can just wrap the character in a span and then do something like this:

```
$('#iamelement').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next(".hidden").slideToggle("fast", function() {
        $this.find('span').text($(this).is(':visible') ? '-' : '+');
    }); 
});
```

This would be for something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="iamelement">toggle thing <span>+</span></a>
<div class="hidden">
    thing
</div>
```

The proof is in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rFeeJ/1/

ADDITIONS:
To make it generic, you need to use classes instead of IDs.  I was merely trying to be illustrative.

```
<a href="#" class="toggler">toggle thing <span>+</span></a>
<div class="hidden">
    thing
</div>
<a href="#" class="toggler">toggle thing 2 <span>+</span></a>
<div class="hidden">
    thing 2 
</div>
<a href="#" class="toggler">toggle thing 3 <span>+</span></a>
<div class="hidden">
    thing 3
</div>

$('a.toggler').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next(".hidden").slideToggle("fast", function() {
        $this.find('span').text($(this).is(':visible') ? '-' : '+');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adam... what if I don't have the ability to add unique ID's for each instance?  Also, the second toggle in your example does work.  Thanks!

Comment: That's because I had two IDs in my HTML but only referenced one.  See update above for more info on making it generic without IDs.

Comment: If this answer was the one you were looking for, please mark it as the answer.