# jQuery Toggle html characters +/-

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, character

I'm having a simple problem toggling between +/- characters which prepend a link which opens a dropdown menu. This code works, except I need to remove the div and just have the href toggle.

Any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="toggler"><span>+</span> toggle</a>
<div class="hidden">
 Hidden
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a.toggler').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.next(".hidden").slideToggle("fast", function() {
        $this.find('span').text($(this).is(':visible') ? '-' : '+');
    });
});
```

I borrowed the code from this link: [Need to replace +/- characters with html codes (for example) &#8212; in small piece of jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654838/need-to-replace-characters-with-html-codes-for-example-8212-in-small-pie)

Comment: 'except I need to remove the div and just have the href toggle'

Comment: Sorry, I need to remove this:

    <div class="hidden">
     Hidden
    </div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an updated version:

http://jsfiddle.net/aGKJR/2/

I had it so it only toggled when you clicked the +/-.  Now the whole link works.

Basically, you need to remove the `slideToggle` callback and place its code in the `onclick` function instead.

Comment: updated it - probably could be cleaned up a bit - but it works

Answer (score 0):

[Your code](https://gist.github.com/1090551) works for me. There must be something wrong somewhere else your code. You should post it if you want more help.

Comment: Hi Mitch, the code works right now, but I want to remove this section:    

        <div class="hidden">
         Hidden
        </div>